# Objective-c How can add one UIview at the main view directly from a class?

Tags: objective-c, class

I have this class

```
- (void) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withString:(NSString *)html{
    //CGRect rectFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame; 
    news = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
    web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];
    web.scalesPageToFit = YES; 
    //web.delegate = self; 
    web.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [web loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [news addSubview:web]; 
    [[self view] addSubview:news];

}
```

I receive Sigabrt at line [[self view] addSubview:news];

How can add the UIview at the main view directly from a class? is it possibile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `init<...>` methods should return initialized object - declare it returning value of `id` type. Return `self` in implementation or nil if it's failed.

2) `init<...>` methods have to initialize this object. Read about initializing objects here - [The Objective-C Programming Language - Allocating and Initializing Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html). Basically you have to call one of the initialization methods of superclass, assign `self` to returned value (`self = [super init]`) and check if this value is nil.

Is this class a controller? If so:

3) You have to load it's view - either by loading it from nib on initialization (`init` or `initWithNibName:bundle:` methods) or by implementing method `loadView`. See [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

4) You can be sure your view is available only when `viewDidLoad` is called on your controller. Implement this method if you want to add something to controller's view.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are receiving the abort signal is that your view is not initialized. Instead try adding to `awakeFromNib` call.

Comment: mmm i don't understand... what I must insert in the awakeFromNib method?

Comment: Whatever you are doing for modifying your views (adding subviews, etc.)